# Import Kibana Dashboard in separate webapp

Tags: php, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I have separate kibana interface to monitor logs coming from various servers. Dashboards are made server wise. I have also used searchguard authentication to authenticate user with elasticsearch.

Now I am making a web interface which allow client to manage server in various ways and also must show kibana dashboard only for that server for which user has access. Mean user should not login again in searchguard to see dashboard.

Also I don't want to use iframe to embed dashboard.

Please provide best ways to acheive as mentioned.

ELK and Searchguard version I am using are 5.4.0 .